# Looping through files using lists

Tags: python, xlsx

I have a folder with pseudo directory (`/usr/folder/`) of files that look like this:

```
target_07750_20181128.tsv.gz
target_07750_20181129.tsv.gz
target_07751_20181130.tsv.gz
target_07751_20181203.tsv.gz
target_07751_20181204.tsv.gz
target_27103_20181128.tsv.gz
target_27103_20181129.tsv.gz
target_27103_20181130.tsv.gz
```

I am trying to join the above tsv files to one xlsx file on store code (found in the file names above).

I am reading say file.xlsx and reading that in as a pandas dataframe. 
I have extracted store codes from file.xlsx so I have the following:

```
stores = instore.store_code.astype(str).unique()
```

output:

```
07750
07751
27103
```

So my end goal is to loop through each store in stores and find which filename that corresponds to in directory. Here is what I have so far but I can't seem to get the proper filename to print:

```
import os

for store in stores:
    print(store)
    if store in os.listdir('/usr/folder/'):
        print(os.listdir('/usr/folder/'))
```

The output I'm expecting to see for say `store_code in loop = '07750'` would be:

```
07750    
target_07750_20181128.tsv.gz
target_07750_20181129.tsv.gz
```

Instead I'm only seeing the store codes returned:

```
07750
07751
27103
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what are you getting instead

Comment: see my edits @Vicrobot

Comment: If you run this, `df = pd.read_csv('target_07750_20181128.tsv.gz', compression='gzip', delim_whitespace=True)` ...does it work? Can you print `df.head()` after that?

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not even trying to read in the tsv files yet, I simply want to find which ones in my directory I need before I read them in

Comment: I understand. But they are compressed, so if you want to coalesce them, one way would be to read and concatenate them and save it back.

Comment: ahhh i see thank you @coldspeed

Comment: getting a parse error when i ran that code @coldspeed

Answer (score 1):

The reason your `if` statement fails is that it checks if "07750" etc is one of the filenames in the directory, which it is not. What you *want* is to see if "07750" is *contained* in one of the filenames.

I'd go about it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
store_files = defaultdict(list)

for filename in os.listdir('/usr/folder/'):
    store_number = <some string magic to extract the store number; you figure it out>
    store_files[store_number].append(filename)
```

Now `store_files` will be a dictionary with a list of filenames for each store number.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're assuming a substring search -- that's not how `in` works on a list.  For instance, on the first iteration, your `if` looks like this:

```
if "07750" in ["target_07750_20181128.tsv.gz",
               "target_07750_20181129.tsv.gz",
               "target_07751_20181130.tsv.gz",
               ...                            ]:
```

The string "07755" is *not* an element of that list.  It does appear as a substring, but `in` doesn't work that way on a list.  Instead, try this:

```
for filename in os.listdir('/usr/folder/'):
    if '_' + store + '_' in filename:
        print(filename)
```

Does that help?

Comment: While that looks close to what OP wants, it's also a tad dangerous in case a valid store code happens to also appear in a date. Like what if there's a store "8113"?

Comment: I am aware of the dangers -- however, it matches the logic of OP's code.  However, an update *would* help ...

Comment: don't i need to also loop through store codes though?

Comment: Yes -- I'm not replacing your outer loop, as that doesn't need fixing.